# Improving parts of legacy php code with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

The website I'm working on uses PHP to render HTML templates, and I'm looking to slowly introduce Vue.js to the code base by targeting isolated components or widgets in the website.

An example of the current HTML template would be something like:

```html
<?php if ($this->renderCondition) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo \route\to\linkGenerator() ?>"> link </a>
  <?php $variable = 'value' ?>
  <?php $packages = $this->variablesOjbect['value'] ?>
  <view name="some-sub-component-with-access-to-declared-vars"></view>
<?php } ?>
```

1. First thing I included the vue CDN link in the same file, which is not scalable. If I want to enhance 4 features across a large website, **will I have to link the CDN in the 4 pages**?
2. Second, I mounted the Vue instance on the root element of the feature, I hope this is the right thing to do.

```html
<div vue="first_feature"></div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '[vue="first_feature"]',
})
</script>
```

3. Third, and most importantly, I struggled with passing all this PHP data, which a lot of it lives in the `$this` array, to the Vue app, so I relied on data attributes, which in my opinion looks really messy.

```html
<div
  vue="first_feature"
  data-var1="<?php echo $this->var1 ?>"
  data-var2="<?php echo $this->var2 ?>"
  data-var3="<?php echo \link\to\Something() ?>"
>
</div>
```

So the question is:
**What's a better way to pass this data?**

And for the sub-views `<view></view>` **how do I handle passing props to this**?
I think I need to create standalone `.js` files with Vue.Component instead of what I'm doing, but I'm feeling really lost.

I'm not sure how to make everything in this mess communicate together.

Comment: Pls change thi `<div vue="first_feature"></div>` to this `<div id="first_feature"></div>` and this `el: '[vue="first_feature"]',` to this `el: "#first_feature"`

Comment: Does this make any difference?

Comment: @Sammi what problems do you want to solve with Vue? If you don't have any dynamic js functionality or advanced UI patterns, you don't really need Vue. It would be easier to help you if you had a real example from your code base.

Comment: @Ifaruki why? Both versions behave the same

Comment: @nirazul
There will be some reactive states to handle later on. But even if there's no much need, a decision has been made to slowly switch templates to be Vue-powered for the sake of modernization and a cleaner code base.

Comment: Vue is awesome to enhance server rendered HTML, but if you want to switch PHP rendered static HTML to Vue template code for the sake of modernization, you're in for a bumpy ride. You'll make your content unavailable for search engines other than Google and you'll worsen performance because now the client renders the HTML instead of a server. Just make sure that you know what Vue.js tries to solve and when to stick to server rendered code. A good starting point for you might be inline templates: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Inline-Templates